# How to remove/change an input value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

How do I remove the value 'Anonymous' in this input that I have and replace it with a placeholder text 'Your name' using javascript/jquery? I don't have access to the HTML code.

This is what I have so far, but don't really know where to go from there.

```
document.getElementById('txtYourName').placeholder =' Your Name ';
```

HTML

```
<input id="txtYourName" type="text" value="Anonymous" name="txtYourName"></input>
```

Comment: add `document.getElementById('txtYourName').value = "";`, the placeholder is only visible if the input has no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this second line here...
A placeholder is only seen when the value happens to be blank.   With the code below, you can set the placeholder, as well as erase the default value in your field.

```
document.getElementById('txtYourName').placeholder =' Your Name ';  
document.getElementById('txtYourName').value = "";
```

Demo:   http://jsfiddle.net/723vL/

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**:

```
$('#txtYourName').val('');
```

or pure javascript using:

```
document.getElementById('txtYourName').value = ""
```

If you want to set new value then just put your value inside `""`, like:

```
$('#txtYourName').val('new value');
```

---

With jQuery, your final code should look like:

```
$('#txtYourName').attr('placeholder','Your name');
$('#txtYourName').val('');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7S6x/)**

With pure JS, you final code should look like:

```
document.getElementById('txtYourName').placeholder ='Your name';  
document.getElementById('txtYourName').value = "";
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7S6x/1/)**

Comment: why pure javascript is poor?

Comment: Can you explain why javascript is poor?

Answer (score 0):

That should do it, so long as you are running that script either on an `onload` event, jquery's `ready` event or at the very bottom of the page, once the DOM has been rendered.

Are you getting an error in your console?

Answer (score 0):

try this

returns value:

```
$('#txtYourName').attr("value");
```

sets value

```
$('#txtYourName').attr("value", "");
```

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect.   This changes the `value` of the field, but does not set the placeholder text (or show the placeholder text).   The OP is looking to clear out the value, not set it.

Comment: @Charlie74 : OP can always set "new_value" to "" , right?

Comment: Correct, that would be more of what the OP is asking.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
document.getElementById('txtYourName').value ='some vaue';
```

if you are using jQuery then you can use

```
$("#txtYourName").val('some value');
```

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect.   This changes the `value` of the field, but does not set the placeholder text (or show the placeholder text).   The OP is looking to clear out the value, not set it.

Comment: @Charlie74 he wants to change the value "how to remove/change an input value using javascript"