# How to replace the value attribute in an HTML string?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

Given:

```js
let mystr = "<input class=\"text-box single-line\" id=\"item_Name\" name=\"item.Name\" type=\"text\" value=\"Luis Tiant\">";
```

I'd like to remove the text in the value param `"Luis Tiant"` using JS.

To be clear: I want to change `value="Luis Tiant"` to `value=""` *in the string itself*. This is a string not yet a DOM element. After I remove the value *then* I'll add it to the DOM.

Comment: `document.getElementById("item_Name").value = "";`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/change an input value using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566798/how-to-remove-change-an-input-value-using-javascript)

Comment: thank you for the reply. This won't work. I apologized for not be more clear. mystr is a string and I want to change value="Luis Tiant" to value="" *in the string*

Comment: @CarlosVasquez I've updated my answer below to meet your new requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `input` element and set its `value` to `''` (empty string).

Example below clears the input value after 2 seconds, so you can see it in action:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('input').value = '';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<input class="text-box single-line" id="item_Name" name="item.Name" type="text" value="Luis Tiant">
```

**Update**

Question above has been clarified. If you'd like to replace the `value` attribute in the string itself you can accomplish that using regex and the `replace` method like so:

```js
let string = "<input class=\"text-box single-line\" id=\"item_Name\" name=\"item.Name\" type=\"text\" value=\"Luis Tiant\">";

console.log(string);

let newString = string.replace(/value=\".*\"/, "value=\"\"");

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: @CarlosVasquez if this answers your question please accept the answer by clicking on the gray checkmark under the answer's score, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By initializing the `ID` you can do this as well.

```
document.getElementById("item_Name").value = "Your new Value Here";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting a variable equal to a string of html, then using string manipulation to change the element attributes, I'd suggest using the [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method and related APIs to programmatically create the html element. Then you'll have access to methods like [Element.removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

Answer (score 1):

```html
let mystr = "<input class="text-box single-line" id="item_Name" name="item.Name" type="text" value="Luis Tiant">"
var res = mystr.match(/value=\".*\"/g);
var str = mystr.replace(res, 'value=""');
```